# I've changed my Mysql root Password to blank?

Tags: mysql, passwords, root, reset

Actually i tried to change my password using :

```
update user set password=PASSWORD('NEW PASSWORD') where user='root';
```

Accidentally, i wrote :

```
            set password=PASSWORD('')
```

Now, it asks for a password for `mysql -h localhost -u root -p`

Comment: Just enter nothing & press Enter.

Answer (score 2):

```
mysql -uroot -hlocalhost
```

or even

```
mysql -uroot
```

Answer (score -1):

If it wrong I am sorry, make some spaces, mean, on password press the space key and enter.